# Where can I get maven central updates?

Tags: data-request

Is there a service/feed I can subscribe to that produces new maven central groupId's, artifact's, and versions?

I don't want to scrape maven central periodically. It's too big. I just want to know what was updated when it's updated.

Comment: http://artifact-listener.org is one source if you just have a handful of artifacts you're looking for. But if you're trying to get a much larger set, you'll still need another source